# What's the pattern for Platform Encryption field mask length?

Tags: schema, encryption, platform-encryption

I've enabled Platform Encryption on standard Account and Contact fields, as well as on custom fields. In general masked field values are displayed as 5 asterisks (*****), but there are some exceptions: Contact Last Name, for instance, is displayed as 12 asterisks (************)

Is there a rationale / pattern that's being used by Salesforce to determine how many asterisks to display for a given Platform Encrypted field?

It does not appear to be based on the length of the data actually in the field (which is more secure, and a difference from Classic Encryption) --- for instance, I've created Accounts with 80-character names and 2-character names and they always show up as 5 asterisks when masked.

But Contact Last Name is always encrypted as 12 asterisks --- why is this field special? Why not 5?

[image: Account Name field 5 asterisks]
[image: Contact Last Name field 12 asterisks]

Comment: Hi Zach... Did you find any answer about this. Thanks

Comment: Nope, never got an answer.

Comment: I have found interesting information in the docs, but they rather focus on differences between `*****` and `!!!!!` masks

Answer (score 2):

I guess this question is not relevant anymore, because [since Spring ‘17 View Encrypted Data permission not needed with Shield Platform Encryption](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000247422&type=1) and now fields encrypted by Platform encryption, are not masked at all.

[However, there are several cases when masks do still apply.](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/202/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_platform_encryption_implementation_guide.pdf)

> **Masks You’ll See**
>
> Shield Platform Encryption uses a variety of masks. Some of these
>   simply hide data from view, while others give you additional
>   information about the hidden data.
>
> Note: Masking doesn’t apply to data in custom Lightning components.

Mask `*****` for `Email, Phone, Text, Text Area, Text Area (Long), URL` field types means that

> This field is encrypted, and you don’t have permission to view
>   encrypted data.

Mask `!!!!!` for `Email, Phone, Text, Text Area, Text Area (Long), URL` field types means that

> This field is encrypted, and the encryption key has been destroyed.

Mask `?????` for `Email, Phone, Text, Text Area, Text Area (Long), URL` field types means that

> This service is unavailable right now. For help accessing this
>   service, contact Salesforce.

Mask `07/07/1777` for `Custom Date` field means

> This field is encrypted, and you don’t have permission to view
>   encrypted data.

Mask `08/08/1888` for `Custom Date` field means

> This field is encrypted, and the encryption key has been destroyed.

Mask `01/01/1777` for `Custom Date` field means

> This service is unavailable right now. For help accessing this
>   service, contact Salesforce.

Mask `07/07/1777 12:00 PM` for `Custom Date/Time` field means

> This field is encrypted, and you don’t have permission to view
>   encrypted data.

Mask `08/08/1888 12:00 PM` for `Custom Date/Time` field means

> This field is encrypted, and the encryption key has been destroyed.

Mask `01/01/1777 12:00 PM` for `Custom Date/Time` field means

> This service is unavailable right now. For help accessing this
>   service, contact Salesforce.
>
> Note: You can’t put masking characters into an encrypted field. For
>   example, if a Phone field is encrypted and you enter a phone number as
>   *****, or a Date field is encrypted and you enter 07/07/1777, that data is not saved.

---

The document I have referred above is also outdated.

[The up-to-date documentation is located here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_pe_masking.htm&type=5).

Mask `!!!!!` for `Email, Phone, Text, Text Area, Text Area (Long), URL` field types means that

> This field is encrypted, and the encryption key has been destroyed.

Mask `?????` for `Email, Phone, Text, Text Area, Text Area (Long), URL` field types means that

> This service is unavailable right now. For help accessing this
>   service, contact Salesforce.

Mask `08/08/1888` for `Custom Date` field means

> This field is encrypted, and the encryption key has been destroyed.

Mask `01/01/1777` for `Custom Date` field means

> This service is unavailable right now. For help accessing this
>   service, contact Salesforce.

Mask `08/08/1888 12:00 PM` for `Custom Date/Time` field means

> This field is encrypted, and the encryption key has been destroyed.

Mask `01/01/1777 12:00 PM` for `Custom Date/Time` field means

> This service is unavailable right now. For help accessing this
>   service, contact Salesforce.

Basically this means that they have just removed masks like `*****` and `07/07/1777'.